# Veuillez m'aider à me rappeler d'une expression à 3 mots

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Bonjour Mesdames et Messieurs. Au cours de mes études, je suis tombé sur une expression que j'ai fini par oublier. J'ai du mal à trouver un exemple pertinent de son utilisation, mais elle signifierait une sorte de lien ou plutôt d'intermédiaire entre deux choses ou organismes (par exemple gouvernementaux). Je sais pertinemment qu'en parlant politique on l'utilise le plus souvent.

Cette expression était composée de trois mots, avec le "de" au milieu et un mot finissant par "-tion" à la fin. On dirait "rouleau de communication" ou "relais de conversion" ou quelque chose de ce genre, se rapportant à un engrenage ou une pièce de machine.

Toute piste serait la bienvenue. Merci d'avance.

Comment: Réseau de communication

Comment: Désolé, mais non. C'est vraiment une expression idiomatique employé dans le sens figuré. C'est aussi le nom d'un détail mechanique.

Answer (score 7):

> *Courroie de transmission*. au figuré. moyen ou personne servant d'intermédiaire.
>
> Elle disposerait d'une antenne dans chaque ministère, à la fois
> courroie de transmission et organe de contrôle. *politique étrangère*,
> 2008, Pierre-Henri d’Argenson (Cairn.info)
>
> [ [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/courroie) en ligne ]

Comment: Dans le mille ! C'est une souffrance particulière d'avoir un mot sur le bout de la langue sans pouvoir s'en souvenir malgré ses meilleurs efforts, et vous m'en avez délivré. Un très grand merci à vous, et bonne journée.

Comment: @Harlaehas Bienvenue, pareillement !

Comment: @Harlaehas merci de valider la réponse si elle répond à votre question.